# Cannot find the object "student" because... Why is that?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database named school, with one table named students.
When I am trying to alter the table student, I get the following error message:

> Cannot find the object "student" because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permissions.

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
USE school;

ALTER TABLE student
ALTER COLUMN index_number INT NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Is the table name "student" or "studentS"

Comment: ```SHOW TABLES;``` might help. Or ```SHOW PRIVILEGES;```

Comment: @Bogdan - ups... you are right.

Comment: omg not again... thank you, I am a bit sleepy and I forgot the S from the end, sorry for bothering you with stuff like this xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a select query (or use SSMS) to see if the table exists.

```
USE school;
Select * from Student
```

If above query is successful then table exists but you don't have permission to alter it. If above query fails, table may not be there.